# Implementation and adding items to ArrayList from methods

Tags: java, interface, arraylist, implementation, abstract

Let me paste my whole question. And please consider my English I am a bit weak in it.

Question: A Dispatch system which follows the sales order received to dispatch 
the  items  with  proper  packaging  needed  based  on  the  items  ordered.  Assume  that  the  shop  is  selling Antique items  rich  in  art.  These  art  items 
can be categorized as ‘FRAGILE’ items. Two types of fragile items are 
sold in the shop which are ‘pottery’ and ‘glassware’. Each item needed to be bundled with proper 
packages. Bundling is of two types either ‘BubbleWrap’ or ‘Cushioning’. For fragile items 
bubble wrap is done and non-fragile items ‘cushioning’ is used. 
You  need  to  then  create  an  ARTITEM  class  having  ArrayList of artpieces  and  a  Dispatcher  to pack  different  types  of  artitem  object  which  can  be  identied  either  as  fragile. Salesorder is our demo class which will use Dispatcher to pack an artitem?

I have an interface Artpiece.java. I have ArtItems.java class and I have implemented the Artpiece.java objects in ArtItems.

My problem is, I need to add items in the ArrayList from Artpeice, Artpiece basically will have fragile items. example[addItem(Artpiece artpiece)], then i need to set get the total price from getCost() method. And then show the which fragile item is in.

I dont know how to get the values from ArrayList. And whenever I try to store inside the array list, it gives an error.

Please see my coding below:

```
//Artpiece.java
interface Artpiece{
    public String name();
    public Bundling bundling();
    public float price();

} 

//Bundling.java
interface Bundling{
    public String bundle();
}

//Cushioning.java
public class Cushioning implements Bundling{
    //Override
    public String bundle() {
        return "Cushioning";
    }
}


//BubbleWrap.java

public class BubbleWrap implements Bundling{
    public String bundle() {
        return "BubbleWrap";
    }

//ArtItem.java
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArtItems implements Artpiece{

    ArrayList<Artpiece> artpiece = new ArrayList<Artpiece>();

    artpiece.add(void price());

    //Override
    public String name() {

        return "Pottery";
    }

    //Override
    public Bundling bundling() {

        return null;
    }

    //Override
    public float price() 
    {
        return 25;
    }

    public float getCost()
    {
        int sum=1, total = 0;
        return total += sum;

    }

    public void addItem(Pottery pottery) 
    {


    }
    public void addItem(GlassWare glassWare) 
    {


    }

    public void showItems() {


    }



}
}

//Now I am posting the driver classes.

//Dispatcher.java
public class Dispatcher { 
      public ArtItems prepareFGitem(){ 
      ArtItems artitems = new ArtItems(); 
      artitems.addItem(new Pottery()); 
      artitems.addItem(new GlassWare()); 
          return artitems;
      }
}

//Salesorder.java
 public class Salesorder { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
     Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher(); 
      ArtItems FGartitem = dispatcher.prepareFGitem(); 
      System.out.println("Fragile Items"); 
      FGartitem.showItems(); 
      System.out.println("Total Cost: " +FGartitem.getCost()); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: There are errors in your code. The 'void price' should be removed. Also, changing your naming. It's artpieces, not artpiece. You want to add an artpiece to the list of artpieces, like artpieces.add(new Artpiece());

Comment: Where have you defined the add you use artpiece.add(void price()) ?? Also your price function as you defined it returns a float, why are you calling it using void??

Comment: Also, the location of adding things to the list is incorrect. You can only call the method of adding items in another method, or in a constructor or initializer block. I'd suggest doing it from a method, it's probably the easiest for you. Also stick to the convention of using lower case variables, and upper case classes. your 'FGartitem' should be called 'artItems', or something like that.

Comment: In the addItem methods, you'll need to add the items to the list, like 'artpiece.add(pottery)'. This will, however, probably not work, since your list only accepts Artpiece classes, so you'll need to change that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you for contributing. I solved the question myself after doing some research of my own: You can refer to the answer that I have posted and it is 100% working.The coding is below:

```
//Artpiece.java
interface Artpiece{
    public String name();
    public Bundling bundling();
    public float price();

}

//BubbleWrap.java
public class BubbleWrap implements Bundling{
    public String bundle() {
        return "BubbleWrap";
    }
}

//Bundling.java
interface Bundling{
    public String bundle();
}

//Cushioning.java
public class Cushioning implements Bundling{
    //Override
    public String bundle() {
        return "Cushioning";
    }
}

//FGItem.java
abstract class FGItem implements Artpiece{
    public Bundling bundling() {
        Bundling b = new BubbleWrap();
        return b;
    }
    public abstract float price();

}

//GlassWaare.java
public class GlassWare extends FGItem{

    //Override
    public String name() {

        return "GlassWare";
    }

    //Override
    public float price() {

        return 160;
    }

}

//Pottery.java
public class Pottery extends FGItem{

    //Override
    public String name() {

        return "Pottery";
    }

    //Override
    public float price() {

        return 25;
    }

}

//ArtItems.java
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArtItems implements Artpiece{

    float sum = 0;
    ArrayList<Artpiece> item = new ArrayList<Artpiece>();


    //Override
    public String name() {

        return name();
    }

    //Override
    public Bundling bundling() {

        return bundling();
    }

    //Override
    public float price() 
    {
        return price();
    }

    public float getCost()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<item.size(); i++)
        {
            Artpiece art = item.get(i);
            sum += art.price();
        }
        return sum;

    }

    public void addItem(Artpiece artpiece) 
    {

        item.add(artpiece);
    }

    public void showItems() 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<item.size(); i++)
        {
            Artpiece art = item.get(i);
            System.out.println("Item: " + art.name() + " Packaging " + art.bundling().bundle() + ", Price: " + art.price());
        }

    }



}

//Dispatcher.java

public class Dispatcher { 
      public ArtItems prepareFGitem(){ 
      ArtItems artitems = new ArtItems(); 
      artitems.addItem(new Pottery()); 
      artitems.addItem(new GlassWare());
          return artitems;
      }


}

//Salesorder.java  This is the driver class
 public class Salesorder { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
     Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher(); 
      ArtItems FGartitem = dispatcher.prepareFGitem(); 

      System.out.println("Fragile Items"); 
      FGartitem.showItems(); 
      System.out.println("Total Cost: " +FGartitem.getCost()); 


   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does ArtItems implement Artpiece? logically each item you treat should implement ArtPiece, not ArtItems, where you threat a collection of items. It's like saying a warehouse implements a shelf.

When adding to the arraylist, you must add a item of the type Artpiece (or a class that implements Artpiece), you are creating a method inside the add method, which doesn't really work, artpiece.add(price()) would make more sense, but still won't work unless price() actually returns an artpiece, which logically it shouldn't.